# TinyMCE removes double slashes

Tags: image, tinymce, richfaces

How do you disable automatic double-slases removing? When I put base64 embeded image (< img src="data:image/png;base64,xyz...///...==" alt=""/> in html mode it auto removes double slashes and so the image is corrupted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by writting custom urlconverter_callback...